# Where would you put your new open-source .NET project?

Tags: .net, open-source

I'm currently working on a .NET project that I will probably make open source.

There are lots of places to put it though, anyone have any experience for a friction-less effort? Codeplex? Google-code?

Note: I prefer Subversion for the projects source-control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Google code](http://code.google.com/) is my favorite.** It has similar powerful simplicity and reliability just like other products from the Gmail.

**I would not recommend SourceForge** to anyone. Reasons:

- Version control is slow
- If you wire up integration server to their version control, they may ban your IP just for pinging version control frequently
- UI is horrible and hard to navigate. You don't want to lose users just because of that.

CodePlex is better than SourceForge, but it still has more development friction that I would like to have.

Answer (score 2):

I like Codeplex, and it also has Subversion support.

Expanded: Not really .NET but I just find that the interfaces of the website very easy to navigate and the issue tracker sections work really well (easy to add/easy to update). I also like the fact that you can have pictures and syntax highlighted code snippets on the front page of you project.

Comment: Expand, please. Is there something about Codeplex that makes it particularly suited to .Net projects?

Answer (score 1):

SourceForge, I  would think. Isn't that the leader in opensource projects?

Comment: Got any other reason than just "it's the leader"?

Comment: SourceForge always leaves a bad taste in my mouth whenever I have to go navigate their convoluted download scheme.

Comment: 7 clicks later and you can finally download!!!

Comment: Sourceforge provides probably the best download mirrors around the world. Even though that's probably not that relevant for small projects...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com).

Answer (score 0):

I use CodePlex because the Team Foundation integration in Visual Studio is very good, and you can use that with CodePlex.

Comment: In my experience, codeplex has always been terribly slow (from Europe).

Comment: Even the worst response time, is still faster as leaving Visual Studio and doing stuff not integrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you like git as a version control system you could take a look at gitorious.org for hosting. I have a project with my code at gitorious but issue tracking and alike at google code

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) (untill they cut off free private projects), Google Code (open projects only) and recently I found [Origo](http://www.origo.ethz.ch/) as an alternative to Assembla.